# jQueryUI Autocomplete to show Value rather than Label in MVC4 c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Using the jQueryUI Autocomplete - I'm returning a list of "agents" along with their ID, my controller returns correct JSON eg:

```
[{"tvid":12,"agentName":"Smith Gary"},{"tvid":43,"agentName":"Walls Arthur"},{"tvid":623,"agentName":"Mena Ati"}]
```

My JavaScript is:

```
   $("#tvID").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AgentList/AutoCompleteAnalyst",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { value: item.tvid, label: item.agentName };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    messages: {
        noResults: "", results: ""
    }
});
```

And my view is:

```
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tvID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tvID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tvID)
    </div>
```

The autocomplete shows ok, but when I select a name from the list, it is the tvID that populates the textbox above (which is valid for the database, as it is the tvID that I need) - however, is there anyway of me to show the agentName in the text box, and for it to not cause a validation error when posting to the controller:

**Auto complete shows correctly**

[image: Auto complete shows correctly]

**But shows tvID in the box, rather than the agentName**

[image: But shows tvID in the box, rather than the agentName]

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: not clear... do you mean it shows tvid when you select some lable from the autocomplete list? Lets say if you select Smith Marc does it show some tvid rather than Smith Marc itself?

Comment: Hi @gaurav - yes, when I select "Smith Marc" - it shows his tvID 616, instead of his name "Smith Marc" - so aesthetically it's wrong, but it is the 616 that the model is expecting to be passed back.  Thank you, Mark

Comment: So if everything is fine for you then what do you need?

Comment: Hi - I would need (like) the textbox to show "Smith Marc" rather than the number - but I need the number to be sent to the controller/database (much like a dropdown list displays text, but has an underlying value).  Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it works or not:

```
$("#tvID").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AgentList/AutoCompleteAnalyst",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { term: request.term },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return { value: item.tvid, label: item.agentName };
            }))
        }
    })
},
messages: {
    noResults: "", results: ""
}
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
  return $("<li>")
                .append($("<a>").text(item.label)).append($("input:hidden")).attr("name","some_name").val(item.tvid)
                .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Note: You may have to change your model a bit to use this as now you will be getting values from the hidden field rather than the text box. Text box will only provide the name.

Answer (score 2):

As gaurav suggested, injecting a hidden input tag is about as good as you're going to get for using the autocomplete as-is. Even though the options have a label and value, when you select one, the value is placed into the visible input control and its work is done.

There are a couple options I can see.

**Customize autocomplete**

You could use two inputs, a dummy visible one for the name and a hidden one for the value you want submitted (bound to your model). You can then change the way autocomplete works by writing your own `select` handler that would take the label and put that in the visible input and put the value in the model-bound, hidden input.

Assuming you have the two inputs, the first is visible and takes user input for search, the second is hidden and will store the value for submitting/binding and has a class of tvidValue, you could probably configure the autocomplete like this:

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  //prevent the autocomplete's input from changing as the
  //user navigates the available options.
  this.selectedItem = null;
  return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
  if ( ui.item ) {
  valueCtl = $this.next("input.tvidValue").val(ui.item.value);
  this.value = ui.item.label;
  return false;
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML, something like the following would let you hook the autocomplete on tvidDisplay:

```
<input class='tvidDisplay' />
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.tvID, new { @class='tvidValue', style='display:none' })
```

The downside with this approach is displaying previous values (on an edit page; or after server-side validation fails and returns you to the view). You'd need to add a little function to grab the value from the model-bound, hidden input field and resolve it to a name to store in the visible field. This can be mitigated by using a ViewModel that contains both of these values.

Additionally if the user edits the search field but doesn't pick a valid autocomplete value the `select` handler won't fire and you won't know to update the hidden input's value.

**Custom control that wraps autocomplete**

The second approach - the one I chose - was to create a wrapper on top of autocomplete. It generates a hidden input inside of some HTML that displays the name and an [x] to delete it. The autocomplete box is never bound to my model - it is purely markup. The inputs that are generated are given the appropriate name attribute so on submit they are rolled up and bound by the default model binder just like the other form elements. It supports a single person or multiple, has the ability to restore values from JSON objects (for use on an edit page), etc.

It's still an early version but it's working well internally. I just made some updates to it to be more flexible for using different service endpoints and posted it to [GitHub](https://github.com/ErikNoren/entitypicker) ([live demo](http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/ErikNoren/entitypicker/blob/master/entitypickerdemo.html)). You might want to modify the `getEntityHtml` to alter the way it stores values to the hidden input fields - right now it joins the value and label with a semi-colon. This is useful to us on the server side but it might not be appropriate for everyone. The control uses jQuery autocomplete and is decorated with jQuery UI classes in an attempt to match the page look/feel if you're using jQuery UI themes.

**Full disclosure: in case it wasn't clear by my use of 'I' everywhere in that, I'm the author.**

Comment: Hi @edik-noren - thank you for your reply too - and a link to your solution - I can think of something else I'd like to use that with.  Cheers, Mark